# TinyXml Parser refuses to load file properly

Tags: c++, tinyxml

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Hello>World</Hello>
```

Which is located in the very same directory as all my other files.

And I use this source file method to parse it:

```
void Character::assign_xml(const char * filename) //Assign xml takes the name of the xml file as a string, and uses it to parse the file's nodes.
{
    TiXmlDocument * doc = new TiXmlDocument(filename);

    bool loadOkay = doc->LoadFile(filename);



    if (loadOkay)
    {
        printf("\n%s\n", filename);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s does not work.", filename);
    }

    delete doc;

}
```

Yet, when I pass the string to it, my loadOkay variable amounts to false. Why is this?

My output produces the following:

```
Starting /home/holland/code/qt/chronos-build-desktop/chronos...
id01.xml does not work.Failed to open file/home/holland/code/qt/chronos-build-desktop/chronos exited with code 0
```

Where as an strace provides:

```
futex(0x84579c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
open("id01.xml", O_RDONLY)              = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb773e000
write(1, "id01.xml does not work.Failed to"..., 42id01.xml does not work.Failed to open file) = 42
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't pass the filename both to the document constructor and to `LoadFile()`.  Try omitting it from the latter, as per the examples on TinyXML's site.

If it still doesn't work, print out `doc->ErrorDesc()` (and possibly ErrorRow and ErrorCol).

And read the documentation: http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlDocument.html

Comment: updated error output...Still not working properly. I have read the documentation, and it still hasn't helped me in this regard. I should add that I'm using QT Creator.

Comment: Are you on Linux?  Try running your program under `strace` and looking for file operations like `open` to see if TinyXML is successfully opening your file at all, or if (more likely) it is some kind of permission or directory structure problem.

Comment: I am using linux. How do I run under strace in QT?

Comment: Just run your program on the command line, and put strace in front.  I hope you are able to run your program on the command line, of course.

Comment: Yup. Posted the strace. It's still pretty vague, stating that the file isn't found.

Comment: Well, the absolute path appears to work. Isn't that a bad idea though?

Comment: OK, so the file isn't found.  Now, print out the current directory using getcwd before LoadFile, and see why: http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd - if you want to load by a relative path, the relative path has to be correct--the filesystem won't guess for you.

Comment: @Holland let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2830/discussion-between-john-zwinck-and-holland)

Answer (score 0):

There's a small example of using TinyXML for parsing on that page: Tiny XML Parser Example

Here's the exemple with tiny modifications:

```
#include "tinyxml.h" 

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

void Parcours( TiXmlNode* node, int level = 0 )
{
    cout << string( level*3, ' ' ) << "[" << node->Value() << "]";
    if ( node->ToElement() )
    {
        TiXmlElement* elem = node->ToElement();
        for ( const TiXmlAttribute* attr = elem->FirstAttribute(); attr; attr = attr->Next() )
            cout << " (" << attr->Name() << "=" << attr->Value() << ")";
    }
    cout << "\n";     

    for( TiXmlNode* elem = node->FirstChild(); elem; elem = elem->NextSibling() )
        Parcours( elem, level + 1 );
} 

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    TiXmlDocument doc("C:/test.xml" );
    bool loadOkay = doc.LoadFile();
    if ( !loadOkay ) {
        cerr << "Could not load test file. Error='" << doc.ErrorDesc() << "'. Exiting.\n";
        return 1;
    } 
    Parcours( doc.RootElement() );
}
```

You could try it with your xml file (it worked for me) or a xml document like this:

```
<Parent>
    <Child1 test="program" />    
    <Child2>
        <Node number="123456789" />      
    </Child2>
    <Child3>        
        <Hello World="!!!" />
    </Child3>    
</Parent>
```